# Reading PNG Comments (uncompressed zTXt data)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to read PNG comments in iOS without doing manual data parsing?  I have PNG files that store metadata that I would like to access when I load them to a UIImage object, but I haven't been able to find any easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any easy way to do it; I don't see it mentioned in the [list of properties available from a CGImageSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005103), for example. And there certainly isn't a way to do it from a UIImage, that class doesn't (publicly) preserve any metadata beyond the EXIF orientation flag, and that only so the code doesn't have to rotate the image when reading it.

Fortunately PNG is [well-documented](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html) and very easy to parse, so extracting the zTXt chunks shouldn't be much of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Any data you can get to "easily" without writing your own data parser is going to be inside the image properties dictionary.

```
UIImage* image; // assuming this exists
NSData* pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

CGImageSourceRef imgSrc = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(pngData,NULL);
CFDictionaryRef imgSrcProps = CGImageSourceCopyProperties(imgSrc,NULL);

NSDictionary* imgSrcPropDict = (NSDictionary*)imgSrcProps;
NSLog(@"image properties: %@", imgSrcPropDict);

CFRelease(imgSrcProps);
CFRelease(imgSrc);
```

Hope this helps, not sure if what you are looking for is in there